# Ember saving one to one, using promises

Tags: ember.js, promise, one-to-one

im trying to save a few models with one to one relation which initializes on a  single controller action. Ive split things into small functions to use promises. I've been trying to make it work for almost a week and cant find the solution. I've also made a jsbin:
http://jsbin.com/enoYONAv/1/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `valueBinding` you can use `selectionBinding` in your `Ember.Select`, to retrieve the selected model directlly instead of your id. For example:

```
{{
   view Ember.Select
   prompt="Gender"
   contentBinding="genders"
   optionValuePath="content.id"
   optionLabelPath="content.type"
   selectionBinding="selectedGender"
}}
```

So in you action you can do:

```
var gender = this.get('selectedGender');

...

var hash = {
    name : personName,
    gender : gender,
    organization : organization
};

this.savePerson(hash).then(this.saveAgentAssociation(agentAddress));
```

This is your updated jsbin please give a look http://jsbin.com/efeReDer/1/edit